# Do not increment score for wrong checkbox selection

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have a simple quiz app with 5 radio buttons and 5 checkbox. The checkbox question have multiple answers , for such one question there are 3 right answers out of 4 checkbox. When user selects the wrong one among three boxes the score is still getting incremented, how to not increment for wrong selection checkbox.

MainActivity :

```
[public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

/**
     * The number of correct answers
     */
    int score = 0;

public void end_Test(View view) {
        EditText nameField = findViewById(R.id.name_field);
        String name = nameField.getText().toString();

        //Called question checking methods
        question_1();
        question_2();
        question_3();
        question_4();
        question_5();
        question_6();
        question_7();
        question_8();
        question_9();
        question_10();

        // Display the test result on the screen
        String test_result = createTestResult(name, score);
        displayResult(test_result);

        // Disabled "End Test" button after clicking on it.
        Button endTestButton = findViewById(R.id.end_test_button);
        endTestButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

public void question_10() {
        // Figure out if the user chose "Ipad" answer
        CheckBox IpadCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.ipad_checkbox);
        boolean hasIpad = IpadCheckBox.isChecked();

        // Figure out if the user chose "Imac" answer
        CheckBox ImacCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.imac_checkbox);
        boolean hasImac = ImacCheckBox.isChecked();

        // Figure out if the user chose "Ipod" answer
        CheckBox IpodCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.ipod_checkbox);
        boolean hasIpod = IpodCheckBox.isChecked();

        // Figure out if the user chose "Ipod" answer
        CheckBox ImaxCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.imax_checkbox);
        ImaxCheckBox.isChecked();


        if (hasIpad) {
            if (hasImac){
                if (hasIpod){
                    increment_score();
                }
            }
        }
    }

/**
     * This method is called when user selected the correct answer.
     * Added +1 to score for each correct answer
     */
    private int increment_score() {
        score = ++score;
        return score;
    }

}][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should multiple answers be possible? If not, I would replace the `CheckBoxe's` with `RadioButton's`. And at the end I would only check for the correct solution:

```
RadioButton rbIPod = findViewById(R.id.imax_checkbox);

if(rbIPod.isChecked()){
    increment_score();
}
```

**EDIT based on your comment**

So you are going like this:

```
if (hasIpad && hasImac && hasIpod && !hasImax) {
    increment_score();
}
```

In this case you need to select the Ipad-, Imac- and Ipod `CheckBox` to get called `increment_score()`-

Comment: My question has multiple answers and i want to increment one score for all right answers.

Comment: @Rajashekar no problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

you are incrementing the score under the condition that the three answers are right, omitting the fourth one `Imax`, you would rather do something like that :

```
if (hasIpad)  
      increment_score();
if (hasImac)  
      increment_score();

     //.....
```

and do the same thing for the two other ones.

Comment: By doing this score is incrementing even on selection of wrong item checkbox. i don't want to increment score in wrong item selection.

Answer (score 0):

The logic you written below is:

```
    if (hasIpad) {
        if (hasImac){
            if (hasIpod){
                increment_score();
            }
        }
    }
```

It means 'if HasIpad is true, then if HasImac is true, then if hasIpod is true, then Increment score.'

What it should be: (lets assume the correct answer is HasImac)

```
    If(HasImac)
    {
     increment();
    }
    else
    {
     you_disappoint_me();
    }
```

Comment: I have checkbox for this quiz question. There are 3 multiple answers for this question , so when user selects the item which is wrong one i need to stop incrementing the score.